# Substitute regex group in prompt when replace with confirmation

Tags: regular-expression, replace

I am using vim to replace with simple regex:
`%s/Foo\(.\)/Bar\1Biz/gc`

I wanna to confirm each occurence and Vim asks:

`replace with Bar\1Biz (y/n/a/q/l/^E/^Y)?`

Is it possible to substitute group (`\1`) in prompt to see resulting sting for each occurrence?

Comment: I am pretty sure there was an issue for that, but cannot find it currently

Comment: This would be a valid improvement request. Christian couldn't find the issue on GitHub. I also had a look and didn't find anything. You should also search the currently open issues. If you don't find anything, open a new one.